# Establishing AAs protonation - which software to choose?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, computational-chemistry, molecular-modeling, gromacs, amber

I need to establish protonation of aminoacids composing the studied protein. To my knowledge there are H++ and Pdb2pqr servers that are able to do that. However,  they yield quite much different outputs. Do you know about something else I may try to compare with? Maybe there’s something better than these?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to study the protonation state of different aminoacids in a protein? Or you do want to ensure that the protonation states you have are correct? This [link](https://charmm-gui.org/) has tools to do protonation.

Answer (score 1):

[Propka](https://github.com/jensengroup/propka) is a standard option used to establish the protonation states of residues in MD. This is a module that can be installed in python. There is thorough [documentation](https://propka.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) online regarding its use. There two main papers that provide a reference to their methods are: https://doi.org/10.1021/ct100578z and https://doi.org/10.1021/ct200133y.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/2773)

Comment: I have added the two main papers that relate to the software, and added some information. The poster requested another method, and I have provided one.

Comment: "Propka is a standard option used to establish the protonation states of residues in MD. This is a module that can be installed in python. There is thorough documentation online regarding its use. There two main papers that provide a reference to their methods are https://doi.org/10.1021/ct100578z and https://doi.org/10.1021/ct200133y." **261 characters left**. I don't think this answer deserves a downvote (especially now that you made it longer than just 1 line), but it's so short that it fits in the comment box. Please see the highest scoring answers on this site for examples of what's okay.

Comment: I need some 'points' on this site before I can comment. If you can move it to the comment section of their post, that's fine. It's a short question with a short answer.